# Google Maps API problem with CSS border: right;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very simple flexbox container with four divs (one with the Google Maps API).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-1"></div>
    <div class="main-2"></div>
    <div class="main-3"></div>
    <div id="map" class="main-map"></div>
</div>
```

To make a simple border, I tried:

```
.container div:not(#map) {
    border-right: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

and

```
.container div:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

The borders were showing up but those same borders were showing up in my map and I have no idea how to get rid of them... - image:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJAu6.png)

Alternatively, would there not be another way to create such borders in a flexbox? Something like a:

```
flex-gap: 10px #FFFFFF;
```

or something like that...

Comment: Still not very clear, what you want to achieve. And, where are other 3 boxes?

Comment: I took a screenshot of the full div element: https://imgur.com/Vf77r0z. I hope this clears things up!

Comment: We don't need screenshots, we need a [mcve]. And as a side note it should probably take 20 seconds to debug this with your browser developer tools.

Comment: Please post the html structure under the `.container` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not 100% sure of the problem, it seems that the issue is that your CSS targets things that it should not.

Google maps will add multiple div elements under the `#map` element, and your CSS rule matches those as well, so they get the border too.

You will need to either reset your border for the child divs of `#map` or exclude them.

If the bordered `div` elements are direct children of the `.container` then use

```
.container > div:not(#map) {
    border-right: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

If you have a more convoluted structure and you cannot directly exclude the children of `#map` then reset them.

```
.container div {
    border-right: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.container #map div {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabriele! Yes the problem was that I didn't know how to isolate the whole div (#map) element.